# How to import both VRFConsumerBase and ChainlinkClient in same contract

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x, chainlink

I would like to use 2 of the functionalities of Chainlink, One is VRF and another is making API requests.

So I am importing two libraries together. [ChainlinkClient.sol](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/) and [VRFConsumerBase.sol](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol)

Which have an Interface and a Library same so I get these errors...

```
browser/do-escrow.sol:4:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol"; ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ browser/LinkTokenInterface.sol:3:1: The previous declaration is here: interface LinkTokenInterface { ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

and the other one...

```
browser/do-escrow.sol:4:1: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol"; ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ browser/SafeMath.sol:16:1: The previous declaration is here: library SafeMath { ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

I have tried with changing the names of the library (for e.g. SafeMath) but it doesn't seem to work.

Please help me to handle this correctly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange Jeevanjot! You'll want to separate your contract into two contracts interacting with interfaces. The reason you're getting this error is that both imports also import `LinkTokenInterface` and `SafeMath`, so it's getting confused because it's importing them twice.

Let's say this is your code:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "./VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract DomainOffering is VRFConsumerBase, ChainlinkClient {
```

You're going to run into issues since each one of these imports ALSO imports those packages that are erroring, so you're essentially having them be double imported. An easy solution is to split it up into two contracts, and have your main contract interact with the randomness through an interface.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import {randomness_interface} from "./interfaces/randomness_interface.sol";
```

And then call your `randomness` function like so:

```js
randomness_interface(governance.randomness()).getRandom(lotteryId, lotteryId);
```

The randomness interface could just be a truncated version of the contract:

```js
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

interface randomness_interface {
    function randomNumber(uint) external view returns (uint);
    function getRandom(uint, uint) external;
}
```

With a `governance` contract keeping track of the addresses. Your directory structure would [look something like this](https://github.com/alphachainio/chainlink-lottery/tree/master/ethereum/contracts):
[image]

Where `Lottery.sol` would be your `DomainOffering.sol`.

You can also just clone the open sourced code and fix it yourself if you really want to have them in the same contract, but this can be a nice workaround and a great way to decouple your contracts as well.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation over the example, I will follow this approach. I will deploy the DomainOffering contract and I will split the VRF contract in a separate file.